# Issues with gitlab-ci stages

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've been working on setting up an automated RPM build and I'd like to perform a simple test on the SPEC file before proceeding with any build steps. The problem I am having is that the job always seems to jump to the deploy stage. Here is the relevant snippet from my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

job1:
  stage: test
  script:
    # Test the SPEC file
    - su - newbuild -c "rpmbuild --nobuild -vv ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/package.SPEC"

  stage: build
  script:
    # Install our required packages
    - yum -y install openssl-devel freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libicu-devel sqlite-devel libpng-devel libjpeg-devel ruby

    # Initialize the submodules to build
    - git submodule update --init

    # build the RPM
    - su - newbuild -c "rpmbuild -ba --target=`uname -m` -vv ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/package.SPEC"

  stage: deploy
  script:
    # move the RPM/SRPM
    - mkdir -pv $BUILD_DIR/$RELEASEVER/{SRPMS,x86_64}
    - 'for f in $WORK_DIR/rpmbuild/RPMS/x86_64/*; do  cp -v "$f" $BUILD_DIR/$RELEASEVER/x86_64; done'
    - 'for f in $WORK_DIR/rpmbuild/SRPMS/*; do cp -v "$f" $BUILD_DIR/$RELEASEVER/SRPMS; done'

    # create the repo
    - createrepo -dvp $BUILD_DIR/$RELEASEVER

    # update latest
    - 'if [ $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME == "master" ]; then rm $PROJECT_DIR/latest; ln -sv $(basename $BUILD_DIR) $PROJECT_DIR/latest; fi'
    - 'if [ $CI_BUILD_REF_NAME == "devel" ]; then rm $PROJECT_DIR/latest-dev; ln -sv $(basename $BUILD_DIR) $PROJECT_DIR/latest-dev; fi'

  tags:
    - repos
```

I've not found any questions or online documentation to properly explain this to me so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have all stages in one job which does not work. You need to split it up into individual jobs for the three different stages.

Quote from the [documentation](http://doc.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html):

> First all jobs of build are executed in parallel.
>
> If all jobs of build succeeds, the test jobs are executed in parallel.
>
> If all jobs of test succeeds, the deploy jobs are executed in parallel.
>
> If all jobs of deploy succeeds, the commit is marked as success.
>
> If any of the previous jobs fails, the commit is marked as failed and no jobs of further stage are executed.

Something like this should work:

```
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

do_things_on_stage_test:
  script:
    - do things
  stage: test


do_things_on_stage_build:
  script:
    - do things
  stage: build


do_things_on_stage_deploy:
  script:
    - do things
  stage: deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you assume that the stages are build on top of each other, which is not the case. If one of your stages needs something like pre-installed packages, you have to add a `before_script` directive. Think of the stages as in: test-if-build-succeeds, test-if-depoy-succeeds, etc.